# dataclass hash() of field with type annotation and default value = None is always nondeterministic

Tags: python, hash, python-dataclasses

I am running into some unexpected behavior when trying to hash a dataclass and I'm wondering if anyone can explain it.

The below script reproduces the problem. First, we need to run `export PYTHONHASHSEED='0'` to disable hash randomization so we can compare the hash across runs.

```
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

assert os.getenv("PYTHONHASHSEED", None) == "0"


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    x = 1
    y = None


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Bar:
    x: Optional[int] = 1
    y = None


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foobar:
    x = 1
    y: Optional[int] = None


print("hash(Foo()):", hash(Foo()))
print("hash(Bar()):", hash(Bar()))
print("hash(Foobar()):", hash(Foobar()))
```

Here's the result of running the script twice:

```
>>> py temp.py 
hash(Foo()): 5740354900026072187
hash(Bar()): -6644214454873602895
hash(Foobar()): 582415153292506125
>>> py temp.py 
hash(Foo()): 5740354900026072187
hash(Bar()): -6644214454873602895
hash(Foobar()): -8226650923609135754
```

Note that the hash for the first two classes is the same across runs, but the hash of the last class is different each time. It seems to be the combination of the type annotation with the value None in the class `Foobar` that causes the hash to change. (Incidentally, if I replace `Optional[int]` with `int` I get the same behavior.)

I tried with both Python 3.9 and 3.10 and got similar results each time.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dataclass fields *must* be annotated. The annotation is how the dataclass machinery determines that something is a field. All 3 of your dataclasses are broken due to missing annotations.

---

Disabling hash randomization isn't supposed to make hashes deterministic. It just disables one specific security feature that deliberately randomizes some types' hashes to mitigate hash collision-based denial-of-service attacks.

The default CPython `object.__hash__` is nondeterministic. It's based on an object's address, which is not consistent from run to run. `None` uses this default hash, so `hash(None)` is nondeterministic, and your dataclass hashes are based on their fields' hashes, so the hash of a dataclass with a `None` field value is also nondeterministic. However, since your dataclasses are broken, `Foobar` is the only one where `y` is actually a field.

`Bar()`'s hash seems to be deterministic because it only depends on the hashes of ints and tuples (the frozen dataclass `__hash__` [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.7/Lib/dataclasses.py#L638) builds a tuple of field values and hashes that), and the int and tuple hash algorithms happen to be *close* to deterministic. They're not actually deterministic, though; they depend on whether you're on a 32-bit or 64-bit Python build, and while the int hashing algorithm is [mostly specified](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#hashing-of-numeric-types), the tuple hash algorithm is all implementation details.

`hash` is not designed to be deterministic, no matter what settings you use. If you need deterministic hashing, do not use `hash`.

Comment: Setting the hash seed to get repeatable hashes across runs is actually a fairly common trick, however hacky. I've even seen a sitecustomize which overrides the hash of `None` so that it is not memory-address based, for exactly this purpose. This answer is correct but could be improved to clearly describe the reason why `Bar` has a deterministic hash but `Foobar` doesn't (I'm pretty sure the non-determinism comes in because the former ends up hashing `1` where the latter ends up hashing `None`)

Comment: @wim: People might do it for that purpose, but it doesn't really work. You just end up with weird bugs, like your program breaking on 32-bit builds because a bunch of standard `__hash__` methods are different depending on whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit Python.

Comment: Anyway, I've added a section about `Bar()`'s hash.

Comment: Well, it does work, in fact the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) even say that is the reason it's configurable in the first place! (_Its purpose is to allow repeatable hashing, such as for selftests for the interpreter itself, or to allow a cluster of python processes to share hash values_). And who's running 32 bit these days?!  Anyway, upvoted!

Comment: Isn't it true that the int and tuple (and string?) hash algorithms are in practice deterministic across different runs on the same machine? For my purposes, that's good enough.